# Where is folder ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, genymotion

I got the error: Fail to import OVA file when I try to create the new Virtual device. I read some post in the internet and they tell me delete the image in ~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed folder. But I cannot find this folder. Is it puted in Genymotion folder or in File System?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~/ is your home folder so it should be in 
/home/(yourusername)/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed. However i would check ~/.config for a .Genymobile
Also, were are you importing your .ova file from? I've never used genymotion but my best guesses as to why its failing to import are:

- the .ova is corrupt
- the .ova file does not exist and you need to restart virtualbox or vmware
- the .ova file is not in the directory you are trying to import it from
- the world is ending and your computer does not want to import .ova files

Comment: I found it. It's hidden folder so it just appear when I use Ctrl + H. Thank you, but I still cannot solve the error above :(

Comment: ill try installing Genymotion in a bit to see if there's something I can do. I should anyway to i can make more apps